# How to make a database with Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.js

Does anybody know how you can create a database using the Heroku hosting platform?
I have looked at so much tutorials but none of them seem to work...

I've tried MysQL, PsQl...

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Heroku addon for the Database type you want to create. Then follow the doc for linking it with your app. Also con access the database externally with the settings that can found in Heroku Vars in your app. You also should provide more detailed information in your question, regarding your app.